# BLTouch not leveling

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, bed-leveling, bltouch

I installed a BLTouch V3.1 on my Ender 3 which is using Marlin (bugfix 2.0.x) off a Skr mini e3 v2.0. I updated the firmware using a teaching tech video.

I'm having trouble when using bed leveling. It homes everything correctly, and then moves outside the bed before the probe repeatedly deploys and retracts, without the head moving at all. I attached a link to a video here: [Bed Leveling Problem](https://youtu.be/liTlh8uBiPA)

I have a feeling it  must be something in my config files from looking at other answers here but I really don't know. I attached my config files as well. [Configuration.h](https://github.com/Nghtmare/my-Ender-3-Settings/blob/master/Configuration.h) , [Configuration_adv.h](https://github.com/Nghtmare/my-Ender-3-Settings/blob/master/Configuration_adv.h)

I have the BLTouch plugged into the z-stop for the black and white cords. I didn't need to cut any wires or anything since mine came with the endstop connector piece attached, and the other wires in the Zprobe section (Blue, Red, Yellow) to (`GND`, `+5V`, `PA1`) respectively. As for the firmware, I got it directly off the Marlin site: [marlinfw.org/meta/download](https://marlinfw.org/meta/download/).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

---

Additional information:

I have connected my printer to PronterFace and recieve the following error when sending a G29

```
    Reset.
>>> G28
SENDING:G28
>>> G29
SENDING:G29
Error:!! STOP called because of BLTouch error - restart with M999
[ERROR] Error:!! STOP called because of BLTouch error - restart with M999

Error:Probing Failed
[ERROR] Error:Probing Failed
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing and matching a few older techniques. That's understandable, because "older" means "as of three months ago." But there is a better way now: as of version 2.0, the SKR mini has a full, working port for the BLTouch. You do *not* need to plug it into the z-stop, and you can and should retain your existing z-stop switch.

So:

- Power down your printer and get access to your board.
- Roll back your hardware changes by unplugging the BLTouch and reattaching the z-stop switch.
- Plug the bltouch into the port labelled "z-probe", which is next to the display port. Starting from the pin nearest to the stop switches, the pin order should be Brown, Red, Yellow, Black White.
- Optional: instead of the step above, cut the DuPont connectors off the BLTouch cables and crimp a single XH-5Y connector in their place, then plug that into the board.
- Download the official BLTouch firmware from SKR mini: https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/blob/master/firmware/V2.0/firmware-bltouch.bin
- Install that firmware: Rename the file to "firmware.bin", unplug any USB cables from your printer, copy the file to a MicroSD, insert the MicroSD into your printer and power it on.

...and then it should work.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your instructions and it seems I'm almost good to go. I'm able to run everything for the bltouch ( reset, self-test, deploy, and stow,) and they appear to be working correctly. However, while the probe moves to correct spot now, It still deploys and stows the probe several times while not moving at all.

Comment: I test some stuff out a little more and when it sits in place, I do see that its trying to run the leveling, I see a points 1/25 on the lcd but it never goes past that before stopping as if it aborts the leveling

Comment: Hmm. Mine homes first, then goes to the first spot for leveling. When you run the BLTouch self test, does it click in and out about ten times? If so, are you confident you got the black and white wires in the right order?

Comment: @AbberantAeons I am having this exact same issue. Have you found a resolution??

Comment: Thanks a lot fectin!! Your solution works!
In addition, make sure to download the regular BL Touch firmware from BTT, not the one for Z probing as I had done at the begining!
:)